# How can I get a vue html node?

Tags: vue.js

in the jquery project I can use `$` to get a html node:

```
<input id="msg" type="textbox" onkeypress="onkey(event)"/>
...
var txt = $("msg");
```

but now I am in a vue project:

how can I get the input `<input id="msg" ... />` in my method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ref`

```
<input id="msg" type="textbox" onkeypress="onkey(event)" ref="myInput"/>
```

then in javascript:

`console.log(this.$refs.myInput)`